# Laravel: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel, api

I am creating an API for a store. I am having a problem on cart with this error.

**Migration-**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('carts')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Model-**

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'product_id', 'quantity'];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Controller-**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // user logged in id
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    // product id
    $product_id = $request->product_id;
    // find if item exists in cart.
    $cart = User::findOrFail($user_id)->carts()->where('product_id', $product_id)->first();
    if ($cart != null) {
        // if exists, increment quantity
        $cart->quantity = $cart->quantity + 1;
        // save modal
        $cart->save();
    } else {
        // create a new cart product.
        $cart = Cart::create(['user_id' => $user_id, 'product_id' => $product_id, 'quantity' => 1]);
    }
    // return all products
    return $this->index();
}
```

Strangely, sometimes I am able to persist data into the **carts** (usually first time).

[image: output 1]

Then, i get this **error**.

[image: error output]

**Thanks!**

Comment: **Don't post your code as images**... Code is text; copy and paste your code into the question properly.

Comment: Omg, okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your carts table your foreign key user_id  references on users table

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```